# alias for a external drive in Linux <name+colon>

Tags: linux, filesystems, alias

Is there a way to mount a external drive (/mnt/drive_c)

and use an alias/name as "drive_c:" or "c:" (an alias)

so you can issue commands like:

ls -la drive_c:
ls -la drive_c:/windows/system32

Comment: `c:` is valid for wine so such a mountpoint name should be possible. But why?

Comment: yes,,, that is the idea... would simplify a lot of processes and scripts I had already for windows...